# Promise getting called too soon in chain?

Tags: javascript

Given the following function:

```
function makeTimeout(delay=3000) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
             console.log(`I delayed for ${delay} seconds`);
             resolve(`I delayed for ${delay} seconds`)
        }, delay)
    })
}
```

when I run `makeTimeout(5000).then(makeTimeout(6000)).then(makeTimeout(200));` ,
I get back:

```
I delayed for 200 seconds
I delayed for 5000 seconds
I delayed for 6000 seconds
```

shouldn't these be happening sequentially and the `200` second one be at the end?

Comment: No, because you're making all of the timeouts at the start then passing the *results* as the `.then` "callbacks".

Comment: the result of `makeTimeout(6000)` isn't a function (which is the ONLY thing .then accepts) ... it calls a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're invoking the last two `makeTimeout`s *immediately*, while the interpreter is in the process of constructing the Promise chain. Pass *callbacks* to `.then` instead, which *return* the new Promise:

```
makeTimeout(5000)
  .then(() => makeTimeout(6000))
  .then(() => makeTimeout(200));
```

Live snippet:

```js
function makeTimeout(delay=300) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
             console.log(`I delayed for ${delay} seconds`);
             resolve(`I delayed for ${delay} seconds`)
        }, delay)
    })
}

makeTimeout(500)
  .then(() => makeTimeout(600))
  .then(() => makeTimeout(20));
```

Comment: thanks!  accepted your answer and posted an answer but a question about it working different when moving it to multiline.  If I should delete it, please let me know

Comment: Whitespace doesn't matter in most cases, it should work just fine with or without the whitespace - see snippet. I just made it multiline for readability

Answer (score 0):

`.then` accepts two arguments, `(onResolved, onRejected)` - both expected to be functions.

`makeTimeout(100)` is called immediately, and returns a `Promise`, not a `Function`

It's not an error to pass something else to `.then` as, for one thing, that's how `.catch` works - in most promise libraries, `.catch(onReject)` is simply `.then(null, onReject)` - `.then` simply ignores arguments that are not functions, without breaking the chain

i.e.

```
Promise.resolve(1)
.then(null, null)
.then(console.log, console.error)
```

or

```
Promise.reject(1)
.then(null, null)
.then(console.log, console.error)
```

Will work as if `.then(null, null)` simply isn't there

For the sake of completeness, you could also change `makeTimeout` to return a function - since `.then` ignores any argument that is not a function

note: the extra `()` in `makeTimeout(5000)().then`

It's just as valid - though, I wouldn't use this sort of pattern for such simple code

```js
function makeTimeout(delay=3000) {
    return () => new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
             console.log(`I delayed for ${delay} seconds`);
             resolve(`I delayed for ${delay} seconds`)
        }, delay)
    })
}

makeTimeout(5000)().then(makeTimeout(6000)).then(makeTimeout(200));
```

Answer (score -2):

I tried this and it now works:

```
makeTimeout(5000)
  .then(() => makeTimeout(6000))
  .then(() => makeTimeout(200));
```

but separating to multilines fires them out of order...why is that?

```
makeTimeout(5000)
.then(() => {
     makeTimeout(6000)  
})
.then(() => {
     makeTimeout(200)
});
```

Comment: because in the second code, you are not returning the promise that resolves after a delay - `() => statement` is NOT the same as `() => { statement; }` - it's the same as `() => { return statement; }`

Comment: oh there is an implicit return on the one-liner syntax...sorry